# Bootstrap in React.js

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, reactjs

My simple React hello world example isn't letting me list the items horizontally.

It looks like bootstrap `.col-sm-4` isn't getting applied. I'm sure I'm missing something super simple.

http://plnkr.co/edit/QWCkRzHMe5jUfIMVig2P?p=preview

```jsx
var HelloWorld = React.createClass({

  render: function() {

    return (

      <div className="container">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-sm-4">Left</div> 
          <div className="col-sm-4">Middle</div> 
          <div className="col-sm-4">Right</div> 
        </div> 
      </div>  

    );
  }
});

// Now lets render the component.
React.render(<HelloWorld/>, // We pass the value of the prop through an attribute
document.getElementById('app') // Element to attach component to
);
```

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/TwAdiDJxXpDodcAIs62d?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It actually works ! 
The problem is that the preview panel is just too small, and 'col-sm-4' does not apply. Just open it in a new window or replace 'col-sm-4' by 'col-xs-4' and it will work.

Consider using http://react-bootstrap.github.io/ to get an abstraction of all these classes and use instead :

```
render : function () {
  return (
    <Grid>
      <Row>
        <Col xs={6} sm={4}></Col>
        <Col xs={6}></Col>
      </Row>
    </Grid>
  );
}
```